# wrong subtitle start time when trying to hardcode them into video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am very new to FFmpeg.
I am trying to cut a portion of a video and hardcode the subtitle of that same portion in the output file.
My command is:

```
ffmped -ss 01:01:00.0 -i input.mp4 -vf subtitles=input.srt -t 00:02:00.0 output.mp4
```

I get the output of that portion with a hardcoded subtitile, however the subtitle is from the beginning of the file, not the subtitle starting from 01:01:00.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg normalizes timestamps to start from 0 after seeking. So workaround is to copy timestamps and then set output ss to exclude unwanted portion of input.

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:01:00.0 -copyts -i input.mp4 -vf subtitles=input.srt -ss 01:01:00.0 -t 00:02:00.0 output.mp4
```